# How to use STEP in FOR loop using IF condition?

Tags: excel, vba

If current cell value = 4 then "i" value of **FOR** loop must **STEP** 4 ie *For i=0 to lastrow-6 STEP 4*.
And If current cell value = 3 then "i" value of **FOR** loop must **STEP** 3 ie *For i=0 to lastrow-6 STEP 3*.I tried following code but no matter what value I give to "X" inside the **FOR** loop it always takes 4 ie *For i=0 to lastrow-6 STEP X=4*

[image]

```
Sub pap()
With ActiveSheet
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
x = 4
For i = 0 To lastrow - 6 Step x
If ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + i, 9) = 4 Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + i, 7) = 4
x = 4
End If
If ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + i, 9) = 3 Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + i, 7) = 3
x = 3
End If

Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: if you debug your code, you'll see that the instruction `For i = 0 to lastrow - 6 step x` gets highlighted only once. So no matter how many times you change your `x` it won't change the step count. Another approach would be at the end of the loop `i = i + x` and that would do the same.

Comment: I get it now after debugging the code.And `i=i+x` produced the desired output .Thanks!

Comment: If this "produces the desired output", this only means you make the loop to step 8 instead of 4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I understand your idea, I would advise you not to do this: for-loops are generally known as stepping using a fix value. If you want to step using a variable value, you might better use a while-loop:

```
i = 0
while i<= LastRow - 6
do
  if <condition> then i = i + 3
  else i = i + 4
  end if
wend
```

I'm advising you to consider, not only the question whether or not your code is working, but also: imagine that somebody needs to modify your code (or even you yourself after a large period of time), such strange ways of working make it difficult to work on.

Comment: I did not knew that "For" is used for Fixed stepping & "Do while" is used for variable stepping.Thanks for giving such important tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-think about this and manually move the variable i. You need to be careful because when you write next i, i is moved of steps x according to your code. So the code below does what you wanted to do, and moves manually i according to your variable step width. Then I subtract one because of the next instruction that you need to put.
I hope it does help!

So look at this code:

```
Sub pap()
    With ActiveSheet

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
        x = 4

        For i = 0 To lastrow - 6

            If ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + i, 9) = 4 Then
                x = 4
            End If

            If ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + i, 9) = 3 Then
                x = 3
            End If

        ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + i, 7) = 4
        i = i + x - 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It did help but i found "do while" to be much safer than "for loop", for variable STEPS condition as guided by @Dominique .Thank you though !!

Comment: I did not want to change the loop, since I thought you wanted to use a For. So basically I have implemented the more wordy for loop instead of the more straightforward and less wordy while loop.